# Integer with nested for loops in a 3-dimentional array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is the question :

Within the main method, create a 10x10x10 three dimensional array.

By making the use of nested for loops, store the value of the sum of each of its coordinate positions.

For example: position (3,4,8) = 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class threedim
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

   int threeD[][][] = new int[10][10][10];    
   int i, j, k = 0;


        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
            for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
                threeD[i][j] = k;
                k++;
        }


        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<10; j++)
                System.out.print(threeD[i][j] + " ");
           System.out.println();
        }
      System.out.println();

   }

}
```

I receive an incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[] error, can anyone help me ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where is the error, like what line, and you are only using a 2d array in the loops. What are you doing with k?

Comment: That's because your array is 3 dimensions and you have only 2 `for` therefore you are trying to fill with an `int` the 3rd dimension of your array. Add another inner `for`

Comment: Could you explain the logic here : `(3,4,8) = 3 + 4 + 5 = 15` my Math disagree with you. `3 + 4 + 5 = 12`

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a three dimensional array, you need three nested loops:

```
int h, i, j, k = 0;

for (h=0; h<10; h++) 
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
            threeD[h][i][j] = k; // Is that really, what you want to do?
            // threeD[h][i][j] = h + i + j; seems to be the right thing to do according to your explanation
            k++;
        }

for (h=0; h<10; h++) 
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
            System.out.print(threeD[h][i][j] + " ");
       System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: The correct way would be `threeD[h][i][j] = h+i+j;`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think, you're right, I've added a comment in my answer's code example, since the explanation in the question does not match its code example.

Comment: Its perfect now. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the following line:

```
threeD[i][j] = k;
```

*threeD[i][j]*  refers to the third dimension of your array. The third dimension of you array is a simple array.

So, to set/add *k* to this array, you should specify concrete index.

```
threeD[i][j][z] = k;
```

where *z* is another index.

---

Btw, in this particular example, you can use your *k* as "z":

```
threeD[i][j][k] = k;
```

Comment: Nice answers, you should add that a new loop is needed to use `k` here.